# How can I share a constantly changing array between Parent and Child Component?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have two components, a Parent and a Child component. In the Parent component, I have an array that is empty to start off with:

`publicCrowsOnPerchValues: number[] = [];`

I use this array to display data on a chart using `chart.js`. I am using Firebase's RTDB to store and retrieve the data. Here is how the aforementioned array is populated in the **Parent Component**:

```js
 getCrowOnPerchDataChildren() {
    //get a snapshot of the child added
    this.$childCrowOnPerchSub = this.crowboxService
    .getCrowOnPerchData()
    .stateChanges();

    this.$childCrowOnPerchSub
    .subscribe(action => {
      //set the showUserId to false as the user has already set up the crowbox
      this.showUserId = false;
      //get the index of the key from the date array
      let indexOfKey = this.crowsOnPerchDate.indexOf(action.key);
      //if the index is -1, then the date does not currently exist
      //this means that it is a new date, so we push it onto the array
      //since it is a new date, we also push on the value onto the value
      //array
      if (indexOfKey == -1) {
        this.crowsOnPerchDate.push(action.key);
        this.crownsOnPerchValues.push(action.payload.val().value);
      } else {
        //if it does exist, then we don't need to add the new date
        //simply replace the existing data value with the new data value
        //for the same date 
        this.crownsOnPerchValues[indexOfKey] = action.payload.val().value;
      }

      //reset the bar charts data as well as labels
      this.crowOnPerchChartLabels = this.crowsOnPerchDate;
      this.crowOnPerchChartData = [
        { data: this.crownsOnPerchValues, label: "Number Of Crows That Landed On The Perch" }
      ];
    });
  }
```

In the above function, I am essentially populating the array as the user adds data into the Firebase RTDB. It works off a subscription to the observable.

Now, I would like to pass this array to my Child Component.
In the **Child Component**, I set up an `Input()` variable like so:

```js
  @Input() crowsOnPerch!:number[];
```

Then, in the **parent.component.html**, I pass the array like so:

```html
    <app-child [crowsOnPerch]="crownsOnPerchValues"></app-child>
```

This works, except, I receive the empty array. How might I get constantly receive the array as it updates? Should I use a shared service instead?

Comment: Just a guess: maybe with async pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Detection Strategy works in a way, that with complex data types like `array` or `object` it doesn't check the content inside, it only checks the identity of these data types.

It means that if you want to have the changes reflected in your `@Input` you shouldn't mutate the existing array, but rather create a new one (so the identity of your array will be changed).

You can do that using a spread operator:

```
// Instead of this:
this.crownsOnPerchValues.push(action.payload.val().value);

// Do this:
this.crownsOnPerchValues = [
     ...this.crownsOnPerchValues,
     action.payload.val().value
]


// Instead of this:
this.crownsOnPerchValues[indexOfKey] = action.payload.val().value;

// Do this: 
this.crownsOnPerchValues[indexOfKey] = action.payload.val().value;
this.crownsOnPerchValues = [...this.crownsOnPerchValues];
```

Comment: That's really interesting. It makes sense too, but upon implementing it, I am still getting an undefined/empty array in the child component. After making the changes, the charts and data etc all work in the parent component.

Comment: it would be nice, if you could share code of your child component too

Comment: Sorry about that, the child component is bare right now. The only thing I am doing is `console.log(crowsOnPerch)` in `ngOnInit()` to test out the output of the array.

Comment: That may be a problem. `ngOnInit()` is fired only once, at the very beginning, when your array is empty. Try to put the console log into `ngOnChanges()`, or just print values in the child component's template via the `for` loop.

Comment: Ah yes of course! I forgot about how `ngOnInit()` works. `OnChanges` did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The "reactive" way to do it is to make your array an Observable stream and then to wire up the child component to receive it as an Input. It should look something like this,

**Parent component**

***.ts**

```
public myArray$: BehaviorSubject<number[]> = new BehaviorSubject<number[]>([]);
```

When your array changes, push that change to the Observable stream

```
this.myArray$.next([1, 2, 3]);
```

***.html**

```
<child-component [myArrayInput]="myArray$ | async">
```

Child component

***.ts**

```
@Input() myArray: number[];
```

I am using a [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) to allow the use of the .next() function, but you could do this with a simple Observable as well.

The reason that it is not working the way you have it is Angular's change detection. It won't detect the changes inside of the array, only a change to the entire reference. You would have to create an entirely new array and assign it to the variable you are passing to the child component each time there was a change.

Comment: Passing observable as `@Input` value is usually a bad practice. You should try to keep your child components as dumb as possible.

Comment: Fair point, I will remove that bit from the answer.